# Magento Products Imports not processing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I was trying to upload products through CSV but it fails (Dataflow Profiles ) . It goes to import screen after i upload and save file  ,says 1000 rows found and show 0 processed and no update after that . 
I tried with small number of rows, Still same . 
Now I am at least trying to update the attributes .
This is the sample csv format

sku,weight
xyxsku123,25
xyzsku124,25
xyzsku125,50

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The import can be a bit bitchy.
Try to export one product and then use this file to copy your new values inside.
Instead of MS Excel use LibreOffice and make sure that you select ; or , as field delimiter and enclose all values in ".

If everything won't work or if you like it more convenient, try: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/